# How to remove records with first three numeric caracters? pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some code that groups by the first 3 characters of a selected column:

```
res = (excel_file.groupby([excel_file["Column"].str[:3]])
                       .sum()
                       .reset_index()
                       .replace(replace_map))
```

I need it to also exclude values ​​where the first three characters are numbers. And did not include new excluded rows in the `res` table. Please help with implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match and exclude the rows starting with three digits:

```
idx = excel_file["Column"].str.match('^\d{3}')

res = (excel_file.groupby([excel_file["Column"][~idx].str[:3]])
                       .sum()
                       .reset_index()
                       .replace(replace_map))
```